# I want to append the whole list to each other

Tags: python, list, append

```
totalpair = [[350, 1], [731, 1], [1441, 985], [327, 1], [1152, 985], [1593, 985], [1459, 985], [1735, 1616], [1703, 1616], [586, 1]]
totalprob = [0.0010193679918450561, 0.0010193679918450561, 0.0011627906976744186, 0.0010193679918450561, 0.0011627906976744186, 0.0011627906976744186, 0.0011627906976744186, 0.0029940119760479044, 0.0029940119760479044, 0.0011627906976744186]
```

I want to append the each totalprob's entry mapped into the totalpair one by one. and my code is :

```
for i in range(len(totalpair)):
    final = final.append(totalpair[i].append(totalprob[i]))
    print(final)
```

Comment: thisfor i in range(len(totalpair)):
    final = final.append(totalpair[i].append(totalprob[i]))
print(final)

Comment: This makes my eyes bleed.

Comment: You could format the code a little so it appears more readable in SO. There is an help link for learning how to format (markdown).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using list comprehension:

```
final_list = list(totalpair)
[x.append(y) for x,y in zip(final_list, totalprob)]
print final_list
```

This will give you a list like this

```
[[350, 1, 0.0010193679918450561], [731, 1, 0.0010193679918450561], [1441, 985, 0.0011627906976744186], [327, 1, 0.0010193679918450561], [1152, 985, 0.0011627906976744186], [1593, 985, 0.0011627906976744186], [1459, 985, 0.0011627906976744186], [1735, 1616, 0.0029940119760479044], [1703, 1616, 0.0029940119760479044], [586, 1, 0.0011627906976744186]]
```

If you don't care for the original totalpair list you can avoid the full copy of the list and just update totalpair in place.

Comment: My python 3+, so it does not give the list, by the way, the result is total different from yours. 

map(lambda x,y: x, totalpair, totalprob)
<map object at 0x1018e6748>

if I use list (map(lambda x,y: x, totalpair, totalprob)), it did not show the append effect. could you try to help find this problem. Thank you